# Changing the evaluation metric of a model_selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to modify the example from this [tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/) to use my own data.

In the tutorial Y-data can only have 3 different values, but in my case it can be between 0 and 200. I consider it a successful estimate if the prediction gets to +-3.

I suspect I have to make some modification to the *scoring* variable, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
import pandas
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC

url = "testdata2.csv"
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url)


# Test options and evaluation metric
seed = 7
scoring = 'accuracy'

# Split-out validation dataset
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:6]
Y = array[:,6]


validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)



# Spot Check Algorithms
models = []

models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(cv_results)
```

Comment: `...can be between 0 and 200. I consider it a successful estimate if the prediction gets to +-3...` sounds like you have a regression problem. In that case it would be better with "mean squared error" or something similar. If it is a classification problem, and you want to score it as a successful estimate if it is +-3 close to the real value, you should write your own custom function for scoring and pass it to `model_selection`. But if it is a classification problem, a label that is +-3 close to another should not be successful, and maybe on the contrary should be accounted as a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks you. It is indeed a regression problem. I tried using "mean_squared_error' and my results now come out as mean() = -7046264.46 and std() = 2361688